# Weblink in documentation

Tags: doxygen

How do I make doxygen to generate clickable hyperlink? Something like this

[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

The docs I am generating are HTML only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do it the same way you would do it in HTML, i.e.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

See http://www.doxygen.org/autolink.html for more info.